# C#: How to fill textbox depending on the value in the database

Tags: c#

I have this application that search for Address of a customer in Database. I added a 4 `Textbox` namely `txtAddr1`, `txtAddr2`, `txtAddr3` and `txtAdd4` that will display the Address of the Customer in the Database. In the Database there are 6 Fields for the Address, these are `Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, CityPostalcode and AttentionTo`. I need to do the following:

If all field of the address(`Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, CityPostalcode and AttentionTo`) in the database are not empty. Then,

```
txtAddress1.Text = Address1 + " " + Address2;
txtAddress2.Text = Address3 + " " + Address4;
txtAddress3.Text = CityPostalcode;
txtAddress4.Text = AttentionTo;
```

If Address3 and Address4 are empty,

```
txtAddress1.Text = Address1;
txtAddress2.Text = Address2;
txtAddress3.Text = CityPostalcode;
txtAddress4.Text = AttentionTo;
```

And other scenarios like if Address3 is empty, Address1 and Address3 is empty etc etc.

I know that I can handle this using `If...Else` condition but my question would be, Is there any other way to do this? Or will I stick in doing the `If...Else` condition on every scenarios? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a typo there, shouldn't the second block of code be `txtAddress2.Text = Address2`

Comment: You could use the ternary operator, which would be more succinct. `txtAddress1.Text = SomeBooleanValue ? Address1 + " " + Address2 : Address1;`

Comment: `SomeBooleanValue` would be a value determining if you had all the data.

Comment: Thanks, but i mentioned there that that there are many other scenarios like  Addres1 and Address2 is empty, then `txtAddress1.Text = Address3, txtAddress2.Text=Address4, txtAddress3.Text = Citypostcode and txtAddress4.text=AttentionTo`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use a ternary operator `?:` saying

```
txtAddress1.Text = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address2)) 
                                  ? Address1 + " " + Address2 
                                  : Address1;
```

Comment: Some scenarios will be Addres1 and Address2 is empty. Needs that `txtAddress1.Text= Address3, txtAddress2.Text=Address4, txtAddress3.Text = Citypostcode and txtAddress4.text=AttentionTo`

Comment: @Zhyke, have given a clear example ... you can now work on it and change accordingly per your requirement

Comment: means, i still need to find an empty one then set the value? I need to list all possible scenarios then do the ternary operations?

Answer (score 0):

I would create some extra read-only properties on the address class that determine what state.

```
class Address
{
    public bool DoesntHaveAddress3or4 { get { return string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(this.Address3) && string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(this.Address4); } }
    public bool DoesntHaveAddress3 { get { return string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(this.Address3); } }
}
```

Then you can use this in setting your textboxes:

```
if (address.DoesntHaveAddress3or4) {
   // set the appropriate text boxes.
}
```

There are more complicated patterns you could use - but this will achieve exactly what you want and be far more descriptive about what you're doing.

Comment: don't you think you are over complicating this?

Comment: Not when you start adding many many different scenarios, you encapsulate each scenario into a boolean value which accurately describes what the scenario is. Then with an `if` statement you can set the appropriate properties. I would personally use the template method pattern to achieve this or maybe the bridge pattern. But I think then that would complicate it

Comment: don't think you need to define a class for this ... you can even encapsulate in a local boolean field unless the same condition would be evaluated again ... which may not be

Comment: I don't know what structure his address class is coming in - or even if he has one. I just wanted to keep that business-view (ish...) logic away from the view logic